# Format problems in Vue project

Tags: vue.js, visual-studio-code, vetur, volar

I have VS Code installed since long time ago, many extensions, some deprecated, etc. In my Vue project since a while ago sometimes I get the HTML template attributes with extra white space around them.

Here is how it should be:

```
<wiskModal v-model="onlineCatalogVisible" size="lg" hideFooter :title="onlineItemSearchTitle" extraLarge>
  <onlineItemSearch v-model="onlineItem" v-if="purchaseOrder && onlineCatalogVisible" :startQuery="searchOnlineQuery"
    :distributor="purchaseOrder.to.distributor" :partnerVenue="purchaseOrder.to.partner_venue" />
</wiskModal>
```

Here is how it is after I save the file:

```
<wiskModal v-model=" onlineCatalogVisible " size="lg" hideFooter :title=" onlineItemSearchTitle " extraLarge>
  <onlineItemSearch v-model=" onlineItem " v-if=" purchaseOrder && onlineCatalogVisible " :startQuery=" searchOnlineQuery "
    :distributor=" purchaseOrder.to.distributor " :partnerVenue=" purchaseOrder.to.partner_venue " />
</wiskModal>
```

I have Prettier, Volar, Eslint.

In this question I need help fixing the format, or at least I need to know what is causing it. Is it a conflict, is it a bug in an extension?

Most probably I have some conflicting or outdated configs.

VS Code settings relevant to formatting:

```
{
    "editor.formatOnType": true,
    "emmet.syntaxProfiles": {
      "vue-html": "html",
      "vue": "html"
    },
    "emmet.includeLanguages": {
      "vue-html": "html"
    },  
    "html.format.enable": true,
    "html.suggest.ionic": false,
    "html.suggest.angular1": false,
    "files.trimTrailingWhitespace": true,
    "typescript.format.insertSpaceBeforeFunctionParenthesis": false,
    "javascript.format.insertSpaceBeforeFunctionParenthesis": false,
    "prettier.semi": false,  
    "[javascript]": {
      "editor.defaultFormatter": "esbenp.prettier-vscode"
    },  
    "editor.codeActionsOnSave": {
      "source.fixAll.eslint": true
    },
    "html.format.wrapAttributes": "preserve",
    "[html]": {
      "editor.defaultFormatter": "esbenp.prettier-vscode"
    },
    "editor.renderWhitespace": "none",
    "editor.linkedEditing": true,
    "prettier.arrowParens": "avoid",
    "prettier.configPath": ".prettierrc.json",
    "eslint.format.enable": true,
    "[vue]": {
      "editor.defaultFormatter": "Vue.volar"
    },
    "[json]": {
      "editor.defaultFormatter": "esbenp.prettier-vscode"
    },  
    "prettier.embeddedLanguageFormatting": "off",
    "prettier.enableDebugLogs": true,
    "editor.formatOnSave": true,
    "html.format.wrapLineLength": 0,
    "html.format.contentUnformatted": "",
    "editor.guides.indentation": true,
    "[jsonc]": {
      "editor.defaultFormatter": "vscode.json-language-features"
    },
    "[scss]": {
      "editor.defaultFormatter": "esbenp.prettier-vscode"
    },
    "volar.format.initialIndent": {    
      "html": true
    },  
    "[css]": {
      "editor.defaultFormatter": "esbenp.prettier-vscode"
    },
    "volar.inlayHints.eventArgumentInInlineHandlers": false,
  }
```

.prettierrc.json

```
{
  "trailingComma": "none",
  "singleQuote": true,
  "bracketSameLine": true,
  "jsxBracketSameLine": true,
  "printWidth": 220,
  "tabWidth": 2,
  "semi": false,
  "useTabs": false,
  "bracketSpacing": true,
  "eslintIntegration": true,
  "htmlWhitespaceSensitivity": "ignore",
  "arrowParens": "avoid"
}
```

.eslintrc.js

```
module.exports = {
  root: true,
  globals: {
    COMMITHASH: true,
    BUILD_TIMESTAMP: true
  },
  env: {
    node: true
  },
  extends: ['plugin:vue/vue3-recommended', 'eslint:recommended', '@vue/airbnb', 'plugin:prettier/recommended'],
  parserOptions: {
    parser: '@babel/eslint-parser'
  },
  rules: {
    'import/no-absolute-path': 0,
    'import/no-extraneous-dependencies': 0,
    // don't require .vue extension when importing
    'import/extensions': [
      'error',
      'always',
      {
        js: 'never',
        vue: 'never'
      }
    ],
    'no-empty': [1, { allowEmptyCatch: true }],
    'no-param-reassign': 0,
    'space-before-function-paren': [
      1,
      {
        anonymous: 'always',
        named: 'never',
        asyncArrow: 'always'
      }
    ],
    // allow debugger during development
    // 'no-debugger': process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production' ? 'error' : 'off',
    'comma-dangle': 0,
    semi: 0,
    'no-debugger': 1,
    'prefer-regex-literals': 0,
    'prettier/prettier': 0, // TODO: check if we will ever need this prettier thing!!!
    'vue/max-attributes-per-line': 0,
    'vue/valid-attribute-name': 0,
    'vue/no-use-computed-property-like-method': 0,
    'vue/first-attribute-linebreak': 0,
    'vuejs-accessibility/alt-text': 0,
    'vuejs-accessibility/iframe-has-title': 0,
    'vuejs-accessibility/click-events-have-key-events': 0,
    'vuejs-accessibility/mouse-events-have-key-events': 0,
    'vuejs-accessibility/anchor-has-content': 0,
    'vuejs-accessibility/form-control-has-label': 0,
    'vuejs-accessibility/label-has-for': 0,
    'vuejs-accessibility/no-autofocus': 0,
    'vue/no-unused-vars': 1,
    'vue/script-setup-uses-vars': 0,
    'vue/multi-word-component-names': 0,
    'no-unused-vars': 1,
    'one-var': 0,
    'no-bitwise': 0,
    'prefer-const': 0,
    'no-mixed-operators': 0,
    'no-plusplus': 0,
    'no-alert': 0,
    'no-var': 1,
    'import/order': 1,
    'max-len': 0,
    'import/prefer-default-export': 0,
    'prefer-object-spread': 0,
    'no-underscore-dangle': 0,
    'no-console': 0,
    'no-unused-expressions': [1, { allowShortCircuit: true, allowTernary: true }],
    'one-var-declaration-per-line': 0,
    'arrow-parens': 0,
    'spaced-comment': 0,
    'no-nested-ternary': 0,
    'object-shorthand': 1,
    'object-curly-newline': 0,
    'arrow-body-style': 1,
    'dot-notation': 1,
    'space-infix-ops': 1,
    'arrow-spacing': 1,
    indent: 0,
    'key-spacing': 1,
    'no-multi-spaces': 1,
    'space-before-blocks': 1,
    'object-curly-spacing': 1,
    'no-trailing-spaces': 1,
    'no-multi-assign': 0,
    'prefer-destructuring': 0,
    camelcase: 1,
    'newline-per-chained-call': 0,
    'no-multiple-empty-lines': 1,
    'import/first': 1,
    'prefer-template': 0,
    'prefer-arrow-callback': 1,
    'vue/html-indent': 0,
    'vue/v-on-event-hyphenation': 0,
    'vue/attribute-hyphenation': 0,
    'vue/attributes-order': 0,
    'vue/html-self-closing': 0,
    'vue/no-multi-spaces': 1,
    'vue/html-quotes': 1,
    'vue/v-on-style': 1,
    'vue/mustache-interpolation-spacing': 1,
    'vue/require-prop-types': 1,
    'vue/html-button-has-type': 0,
    'vue/no-unused-components': 1,
    'vue/custom-event-name-casing': 0,
    'vue/no-template-target-blank': 0,
    'vue/v-slot-style': 0,
    'vue/component-definition-name-casing': 0,
    'vue/v-bind-style': 1,
    'vue/require-default-prop': 0,
    'vue/multiline-html-element-content-newline': 0,
    'vue/html-closing-bracket-newline': 0,
    'vue/singleline-html-element-content-newline': 0,
    'vue/order-in-components': [
      1,
      {
        order: [
          'el',
          'name',
          'parent',
          'functional',
          ['delimiters', 'comments'],
          ['components', 'directives', 'filters'],
          'extends',
          'mixins',
          'inheritAttrs',
          'model',
          ['props', 'propsData'],
          'data',
          'computed',
          'methods',
          'LIFECYCLE_HOOKS',
          'watch',
          ['template', 'render'],
          'renderError'
        ]
      }
    ]
  },
  overrides: [
    {
      files: ['**/src/**/*test.{j,t}s?(x)'],
      env: {
        jest: true
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

.editorconfig

```
[*.{js,jsx,ts,tsx,vue}]
indent_style = space
indent_size = 2
end_of_line = lf
trim_trailing_whitespace = true
insert_final_newline = true
```

Extensions list:

```
friendlyName     : Auto Close Tag
publisherAndName : formulahendry.auto-close-tag
description      : Automatically add HTML/XML close tag, same as Visual Studio IDE or Sublime Text
homepage         : https://github.com/formulahendry/vscode-auto-close-tag/blob/master/README.md
repository.url   : https://github.com/formulahendry/vscode-auto-close-tag.git
version          : 0.5.14

friendlyName     : Back & Forth
publisherAndName : nick-rudenko.back-n-forth
description      : Adds go back/forward buttons for easier navigation
homepage         : 
repository.url   : https://github.com/nikita-rudenko/back-n-forth
version          : 3.1.1

friendlyName     : C#
publisherAndName : ms-dotnettools.csharp
description      : Base language support for C#
homepage         : 
repository.url   : https://github.com/OmniSharp/omnisharp-vscode.git
version          : 1.25.9

friendlyName     : Dart
publisherAndName : Dart-Code.dart-code
description      : Dart language support and debugger for Visual Studio Code.
homepage         : https://dartcode.org/
repository.url   : https://github.com/Dart-Code/Dart-Code.git
version          : 3.66.0

friendlyName     : EditorConfig for VS Code
publisherAndName : EditorConfig.EditorConfig
description      : EditorConfig Support for Visual Studio Code
homepage         : https://github.com/editorconfig/editorconfig-vscode/blob/master/README.md
repository.url   : https://github.com/editorconfig/editorconfig-vscode.git
version          : 0.16.4

friendlyName     : ESLint
publisherAndName : dbaeumer.vscode-eslint
description      : Integrates ESLint JavaScript into VS Code.
homepage         : 
repository.url   : https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode-eslint.git
version          : 2.4.0

friendlyName     : Favorites
publisherAndName : kdcro101.favorites
description      : Add files and directories to workspace favorites. Create groups of directories and files. Time saver for complex projects.
homepage         : https://github.com/kdcro101/vscode-favorites/blob/master/README.md
repository.url   : https://github.com/kdcro101/vscode-favorites.git
version          : 2.4.5

friendlyName     : Flutter
publisherAndName : Dart-Code.flutter
description      : Flutter support and debugger for Visual Studio Code.
homepage         : https://dartcode.org/
repository.url   : https://github.com/Dart-Code/Flutter.git
version          : 3.66.0

friendlyName     : Format Files
publisherAndName : jbockle.jbockle-format-files
description      : 
homepage         : 
repository.url   : https://github.com/jbockle/format-files.git
version          : 3.4.0

friendlyName     : GitHub Copilot
publisherAndName : GitHub.copilot
description      : Your AI pair programmer
homepage         : https://github.com/features/copilot
repository.url   : 
version          : 1.89.156

friendlyName     : GitLens — Git supercharged
publisherAndName : eamodio.gitlens
description      : Supercharge the Git capabilities built into Visual Studio Code — Visualize code authorship at a glance via Git blame annotations and code lens, seamlessly navigate and explore Git repositories, gain valuable insights via powerful comparison comma 
                   nds, and so much more
homepage         : https://gitlens.amod.io/
repository.url   : https://github.com/eamodio/vscode-gitlens.git
version          : 11.7.0

friendlyName     : Import Cost
publisherAndName : wix.vscode-import-cost
description      : Display import/require package size in the editor
homepage         : https://github.com/wix/import-cost/blob/master/packages/vscode-import-cost/README.md
repository.url   : https://github.com/wix/import-cost.git
version          : 3.3.0

friendlyName     : JS Eval Replace
publisherAndName : hanneshdc.js-eval-replace
description      : Replaces selected text with it's JavaScript evaluation
homepage         : 
repository.url   : 
version          : 1.0.0

friendlyName     : Prettier - Code formatter
publisherAndName : esbenp.prettier-vscode
description      : Code formatter using prettier
homepage         : https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=esbenp.prettier-vscode
repository.url   : https://github.com/prettier/prettier-vscode.git
version          : 9.13.0

friendlyName     : Sort JS object keys
publisherAndName : zengxingxin.sort-js-object-keys
description      : An extension to sort the js object keys
homepage         : 
repository.url   : https://github.com/SBeator/sort-js-object-keys
version          : 1.0.6

friendlyName     : Sort JSON objects
publisherAndName : richie5um2.vscode-sort-json
description      : Sorts the keys within JSON objects
homepage         : https://github.com/richie5um/vscode-sort-json
repository.url   : https://github.com/richie5um/vscode-sort-json
version          : 1.20.0

friendlyName     : Sort lines
publisherAndName : Tyriar.sort-lines
description      : Sorts lines of text
homepage         : https://github.com/Tyriar/vscode-sort-lines
repository.url   : https://github.com/Tyriar/vscode-sort-lines
version          : 1.10.1

friendlyName     : Vue Language Features (Volar)
publisherAndName : Vue.volar
description      : Language support for Vue 3
homepage         : 
repository.url   : https://github.com/vuejs/language-tools.git
version          : 1.6.0
```

I can't think of other settings that would influence this.

---

Update:
I disabled Prettier, still happens. I disabled Volar, doesn't happen anymore, but I need Volar to have highlight and such. I now need the setting to tell Volar to stop doing this.

Comment: Aren't Prettier and Eslint fighting each others ?

Comment: They might, that is a thing I would like to know too :)

Comment: Well have you tried disabling one of them to identify the one that's messing up ?

Comment: No, they were working nicely together until now. I need them to work together because neither of them has all the features of the other. I will gather the settings I have because without those this question is incomplete.

Answer (score 0):

Some update to Prettier or Volar fixed the problem. Now it is all good.
https://github.com/vuejs/language-tools/issues/3275